# counting up bytes used by PROGMEM

Tags: arduino

Just need a reality check here for determining how much PROGMEM I will be using. In the snippet below I am storing an 8x8 array of bytes. Can I assume (roughly, perhaps there is some overhead?) that this will take up only 64 bytes of PROGMEM

*(I realize this is sort of a "Who's buried in Grant's tomb?" sort of question but I haven't used PROGMEM much and I don't want to assume I have 16k bytes of memory (ATMEGA 168 chip) only to find that when I generate the real project data, it doesn't fit.)*

```
prog_uint8_t datastore[] PROGMEM  = {
 0 , 0 , 0 , 255 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 
 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 255 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 
 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 255 , 0 , 0 , 
 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 255 , 0 , 
 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 255 , 
 255 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 
 0 , 255 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 
 0 , 0 , 255 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0
};
```

Comment: No, there is no extra overhead. Since your `datastore` pointer is actually in SRAM, the only thing in PROGMEM is the data itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured I'd make my comment an answer.. feel free to downvote

- No, there is no extra overhead for `PROGMEM` data. All that `PROGMEM` tag does, is instruct gcc to store the data in flash, in fact, the same as it does for initialized SRAM data. In contrast to SRAM data, which is loaded from Flash to SRAM automatically, to use `PROGMEM` data you then have to use functions that are `PROGMEM`-aware, which internally use uses `LPM` (=load program memory) instruction to load data from Flash rather than SRAM. It takes a bit longer (3 cycles rather than 1 or 2 for SRAM).
- I am sure you realize this, but you don't actually have 16K of flash for your data: if you fill up the flash with data, you don't have space for the program itself :)

Comment: oops...I forgot about my program! ;-) thanks for the replies.

Comment: You can use "avr-objdump -t" to create a map from your elf. And -d for an assembly listing. As to see exactly the Flash and RAM usage for your self. You need to enable show verbose output of compilation from the IDE's preferences, to display the temporary directory that contains the elf file.